# linux_3.0.18.bb has PN of "linux" which is in OVERRIDES,

Tags: yocto

I am following the [hands-on kernel lab](http://www.yoctoproject.org/sites/yoctoproject.org/files/elc2013-kernel-lab.pdf) of embedded linux conference 2013 . In Lab1 i followed the same steps except i work with yocto version of poky-pyro-17.0.1 not poky-danny-8.0.1 when i bitbake core-image-minimal, it gives me errors of

> ERROR: /home/yahia/Desktop/elinux_dev/bake_factory/poky-pyro-17.0.1/meta-lab1-qemux86/recipes-kernel/linux/linux_3.0.18.bb: QA Issue: Recipe /home/yahia/Desktop/elinux_dev/bake_factory/poky-pyro-17.0.1/meta-lab1-qemux86/recipes-kernel/linux/linux_3.0.18.bb has PN of "linux" which is in OVERRIDES, this can result in unexpected behaviour. [pn-overrides]

i don't understand what is the $PN and why this error exist?

if i use poky-danny-8.0.1 , it gives me [this error](http://codepad.org/rzR8gDwl)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PN in this case refers to the recipe name which in your example comes from the recipe file name (*linux*_3.0.18.bb).

There are newer versions of the kernel lab: https://www.yoctoproject.org/training/kernel-lab. The latest version uses recipe name "linux-korg", no doubt to avoid the issue you're seeing.

Comment: 2019 answer: rename your .bb file to <name>-config_git.bb